# How to keep code foldings in PHPStorm/WebStorm like in TextMate?

Tags: folding, phpstorm, webstorm

PHPStorm, unlike TextMate, "forgets" the folded code areas when closing and opening the file again.

Sometimes the foldings open by themselves after search-and-replace, even though there were no matches inside the folded areas.

Is there a way to make PHPStorm remember my foldings in PHP/JavaScript/CSS files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

There's a bunch of related issues in our tracker
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/WI?q=%23Unresolved+folding

Comment: thanx. looking forward for a fix!

Comment: Update: 3.0 EAP has made code folding much more persistent for most files!

Comment: dude. what is 3.0 EAP? plz.. afaik ppl dk all the random abbrevs you use at work roflmaocopter

Answer (score 2):

this can be possible by using comments like this

```
 // <editor-fold desc="My Code009" defaultstate="collapsed">
 // any code
 //</editor-fold>
```